# React Action Requests and Redux Structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, codesandbox

I have successfully created an action doing a call request to the following endpoint

```
https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v2/statistics/{league_id}/{team_id}
```

API Documentation is [here](https://www.api-football.com/documentation#teams-data)

I have created a little [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-frost-8sk6y) in codesandbox where you can see i can display the matchs `wins`, `draws` and `loses` correctly in my component `Stats.js` for the Sao Paulo Team ( it is an example )

Here all the steps i have done, i show you only the relevant code to achieve it

In my reducers i have created the following cases

```
  RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_WIN_HOME,
  RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_WIN_AWAY,
  RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_DRAW_HOME,
  RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_DRAW_AWAY,
  RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_LOSE_HOME,
  RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_LOSE_AWAY
```

In my initial state i have

```
  teamsStatsWinHome: [],
  teamsStatsWinAway: [],
  teamsStatsDrawHome: [],
  teamsStatsDrawAway: [],
  teamsStatsLoseHome: [],
  teamsStatsLoseAway: [],
```

These are my cases

```
 case RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_WIN_HOME:
      return {
        ...state,
        teamsStatsWinHome: action.json,
        isTeamsStatsLoading: false
      };
    case RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_WIN_AWAY:
      return {
        ...state,
        teamsStatsWinAway: action.json,
        isTeamsStatsLoading: false
      };
    case RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_DRAW_HOME:
      return {
        ...state,
        teamsStatsDrawHome: action.json,
        isTeamsStatsLoading: false
      };
    case RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_DRAW_AWAY:
      return {
        ...state,
        teamsStatsDrawAway: action.json,
        isTeamsStatsLoading: false
      };
    case RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_LOSE_HOME:
      return {
        ...state,
        teamsStatsLoseHome: action.json,
        isTeamsStatsLoading: false
      };
    case RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_LOSE_AWAY:
      return {
        ...state,
        teamsStatsLoseAway: action.json,
        isTeamsStatsLoading: false
      };
```

And here my action with the call request to the API endpoint

```
export function getTeamsStats(league, team) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .get(
        `https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/${league}/${team}`
      )
      .then(res => {
        let homewins = res.data.api.statistics.matchs.wins.home;
        dispatch(receivedTeamsStatWinHome(homewins));
        let awaywins = res.data.api.statistics.matchs.wins.away;
        dispatch(receivedTeamsStatWinAway(awaywins));
        let drawhome = res.data.api.statistics.matchs.draws.home;
        dispatch(receivedTeamsStatDrawHome(drawhome));
        let drawaway = res.data.api.statistics.matchs.draws.away;
        dispatch(receivedTeamsStatDrawAway(drawaway));
        let losehome = res.data.api.statistics.matchs.loses.home;
        dispatch(receivedTeamsStatLoseHome(losehome));
        let loseaway = res.data.api.statistics.matchs.loses.away;
        dispatch(receivedTeamsStatLoseAway(loseaway));
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
```

The funcion  `getTeamsStats` is then put in the `fetchLeaguesList` to get the Sao Paulo result as example

This is the relevant code in my component `Stats.js`

```
let Stats = ({
  teamsStatsWinHome,
  teamsStatsWinAway,
  teamsStatsDrawHome,
  teamsStatsDrawAway,
  teamsStatsLoseHome,
  teamsStatsLoseAway,
  loading
}) => {
  let stats = "";

  if (
    teamsStatsWinHome &&
    teamsStatsWinAway &&
    teamsStatsDrawHome &&
    teamsStatsDrawAway &&
    teamsStatsLoseHome &&
    teamsStatsLoseAway
  ) {
    stats = (
      <div className="col-sm-6">
        <div className="card detail-card border-0 rounded-0 bg-transparent">
          <div className="card-body text-decoration-none text-secondary">
            {JSON.stringify(teamsStatsWinHome)}
            {JSON.stringify(teamsStatsWinAway)}
            {JSON.stringify(teamsStatsDrawHome)}
            {JSON.stringify(teamsStatsDrawAway)}
            {JSON.stringify(teamsStatsLoseHome)}
            {JSON.stringify(teamsStatsLoseAway)}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

It works as expected, as you can see in the codesandbox [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-frost-8sk6y) but i do not know if i am doing in the right way with Redux states, call action and Component.

My question is , is it right? Can i make it better? If yes, how should i refactor?

Any refactor and code changes in the codesandbox [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/long-frost-8sk6y) is good to accept the answer

Comment: If the code works as intended, I would recommend asking in [Code Review SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dispatch a single action to update the store for result instead of dispatching multiple actions per field in the result.

**src/actions/index.js**

```js
export const RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS = "RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS";


export const receivedTeamsStat = json => ({
  type: RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS,
  json: json
});

export function getTeamsStats(league, team) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    return axios
      .get(
        `https://www.api-football.com/demo/api/v2/statistics/${league}/${team}`
      )
      .then(res => {
        const { 
          wins: { home: teamsStatsWinHome, away: teamsStatsWinAway }, 
          draws: { home: teamsStatsDrawHome, away: teamsStatsDrawAway }, 
          loses: { home: teamsStatsLoseHome, away: teamsStatsLoseAway }
        } = res.data.api.statistics.matchs;
        const teamStats = {
          teamsStatsWinHome,
          teamsStatsWinAway,
          teamsStatsDrawHome,
          teamsStatsDrawAway,
          teamsStatsLoseHome,
          teamsStatsLoseAway
         }
        dispatch(receivedTeamsStat(teamStats));
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };
```

All 6 actions (`RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_WIN_HOME`, `RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_WIN_AWAY`, `RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_DRAW_HOME`, `RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_DRAW_AWAY`, `RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_LOSE_HOME`, `RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS_LOSE_AWAY`) can be rolled into a `RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS` action and handled as follows:

**src/reducers/index.js**

```
import {
  //..
  RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS
} from "../actions";


const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    //...
    case RECEIVE_TEAMS_STATS:
      return {
        ...state,
        ...action.json,
        isTeamsStatsLoading: false
      };
    //...
}
```

The benefit of dispatching a single update to the store is that `Stats` component renders once as opposed to 6 times when results return from the API.

Comment: Can you please update the demo in the codesandbox to accept the answer? I need each state also in my Stats Component.

Comment: The `Stats` component doesn't require any changes to it. The only files that are to be updated are `src/actions/index.js` and `src/reducers/index.js`